# Downgrade ImageMagick from 6.97 to 6.6.9 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, imagemagick, downgrade, ubuntu-18.04

I've got a `Ubuntu 18.04` box with `Image::Magick` installed but wish to downgrade to the version we currently use on `Ubuntu 12.04` boxes - namely `Image::Magick 6.6.9`.  The reason for the downgrade is that there seem to be too many differences between the latest `Image::Magick` and that on our current production machines so path of least resistances seems to be downgrade.

Any suggestion on what the easiest way to downgrade would be?

**-- basic sys info - new machines**

- ubuntu 18.04
- Image::Magick 6.97
- perl 5.26
- apache 2.4

**-- basic sys info - old machines**

- ubuntu 12.04
- Image::Magick 6.6.9
- perl 5.14
- apache 2.2

Comment: The path of least resistance is going to be to _upgrade_ the end of life boxes. Downgrading this is going to be a NIGHTMARE.

Comment: For reference, the less painful than anticipated approach of upgrading was taken.